# Cannot select text in Safari address bar

Tags: safari, macos

All of a sudden, Safari on my Mac has started misbehaving. I can't select the text in the address bar, and so I can't go to any new websites. When it redraws, it goes all weird:

[image: Facebook page reloading]

I've tried deleting the cache, clearing all cookies, disabling all plugins and rebooting. These things didn't help. I've had to switch to Chrome for the time being. Can anyone suggest some other possible remedies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safari suggestions is broken today.

Go to Safari > Preferences > Search and disable Include search engine selections.

Comment: Oh wow, you made my day. Thanks! Probably will never be turned back on now...